# Windows SVN server and Linux SVN clients - any risk?

Tags: linux, windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I have installed VisualSVN Server on Windows 2008 R2 Server.

The clients will all use Linux.

Are there any incompatibility risks associated with this?

Are there any risks at all?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no incompatibility. All Subversion client versions are compatible with all Subversion client versions using the RA layers (http & svn protocols).